# Python- list comprehension. Removing NoneType or emty list from list of list

Tags: python, list

I would like to remove empty list and NoneType list in my list of lists. This is an example.

```
new_pop=[[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[],[8,9]],[[1,2,3],None]]


value = None
empty =[]
for i in range(len(new_pop)):
    if value in new_pop[i] and [] in new_pop[i]:
        new_pop.remove(new_pop[i])

print(new_pop)
```

my desire result is

```
new_pop=[[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]
```

Comment: My code does not give me the desire result. Please help! thank you so much!

Comment: What is meant to happen with `[8,9]` and `[1,2,3]`, which are neither `None` or `[]`

Comment: Oh i see. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_pop = [sub for sub in new_pop if not (None in sub or [] in sub)]
```

Your code has two errors:

1. You use `and`. `sub = [[],[8,9]]` satisfies `None in sub` but not `None in sub and [] in sub`, because it doesn't satisfy `[] in sub`. You need `or`.
2. You're removing items from a list as you iterate over it. Never do that. Always create a new list, like I've done here.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is remove any sublist that includes `None` or `[]` then assuming that all items in your sublists are `list`s with contents then you can use a guard of `all()`:

```
>>> [x for x in new_pop if all(x)]
[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: Clever, but risky. It doesn't look like it here but maybe the list can contain other falsy things.

Comment: Agreed, but assuming that the sublist contains `list`s with contents which isn't falsy, then it should do what is needed.